# Cassandra schema migration in java

Tags: java, cassandra, schema-migration

I wrote on .NET and Entity Framework for quite a while, and I got used to the Entity Framework Code First Migrations. The idea is that you describe your tables in the code and you create a migration. Which in tern checks the current database schema compares it to the current code and if there are changes it creates/alters/drops tables. After that the migration script is executed and the database schema is updated.

Currently I am developing a Java application that works with Cassandra database. Because there are going to be a lot of tables (replicating data in order to create data views), I want to use the same approach that I used with the Entity Framework Migrations. It is going to be a lot easier for me if I can problematically change the Cassandra Keyspace schema, so that I don't have to write a lot of CQL code in order to add a single property to a lot of tables.

Is it possible to do this with Cassandra? Are there any tools for this?

So far I have found the [Pillar](https://github.com/comeara/pillar) migration, but I don't think that it will do the job.